# Using torch.cat on list of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a list of `torch tensors`

```py
list_tensor = [tensor([[1, 2, 3],
                       [3, 4, 5]]), 
               tensor([[4, 5, 6],
                       [6, 4, 3]]), 
               tensor([[4, 2, 1],
                       [3, 3, 1]]), 
               tensor([[1, 4, 5],
                       [3, 1, 0]]), 
               tensor([[1, 3, 3],
                       [2, 2, 2]])]
```

I want to do a cross validation on this set, so I want to consider four tensors as training, and keep 1 for testing - and I want to do this for `len(list_tensor)` times.

So I thought of doing,

```py
for num in range(1, len(list_tensor) + 1):
       train_x = torch.cat((list_tensor[:num], list_tensor[num:]))
```

The problem is I cannot use lists for a `torch.cat` operation because both  `list_tensor[:num]` and  `list_tensor[num:]` return lists. For example, for `num = 1`,

```
list_tensor[:num] = [tensor([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])]
list_tensor[num:] = [tensor([[4, 5, 6], [6, 4, 3]]), tensor([[4, 2, 1],[3, 3, 1]]), tensor([[1, 4, 5], 
                      [3, 1, 0]]), tensor([[1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2]])]
```

How do I perform torch.cat on this?

Comment: are you getting any `error`? It is fine to use list of tensors in `torch.cat`. `torch.cat` accept any python sequence of tensors of the same type.

Comment: `TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around without using `reduce`.

`train_x = torch.cat((torch.cat(list_tensor[:num+1]),torch.cat(list_tensor[num+1:])))`
Basically concatenate all tensors in the individual list, this returns a `torch.tensor` object, then use `torch.cat` on both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

```
import torch as T
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: T.cat((x,y)), list_tensor[:-1])
```

The basic idea is to apply the concat operator to all the tensors in the list, except the last one, and keep on aggregating the result. You can read more [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Comment: How would I use this if I wanted to slice it in the middle? Say leave out one tensor in the middle of the list and concatenate the tensors before and after it?

Comment: So the iteratable is the second parameter of reduce. You can simply add two list. Something like `reduce(lambda x,y: T.cat((x,y)), list_tensor[:i] + list_tensor[j:])` where you adjust `i` and `j` according to your rerquirements.